# How can I define two different 'distribution' tasks in gradle?

Tags: gradle

The normal behavior of the `distTar` and `distZip` tasks from the application plugin in gradle seems to be to copy the contents of *src/dist* into the zip and tar files, but I have a subfolder in *src/dist* that I want to exclude from the default distribution, and include it for a new (extended) task, possibly to be called distZipWithJRE.

I have been able to exclude this folder in the default task as follows:

```
distributions.main {
    contents {
        from('build/config/main') {
            into('config')
        }

        from('../src/dist') {
            exclude('jre')
        }
    }
}
```

How can I define a second task that behaves just like the original (unmodified) task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what you're looking for is in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html). You need to leave current settings as is and for `zipWithJRE` create and configure custom distribution:

```
distributions {
    zipWithJRE {
        baseName = 'zipWithJRE'
        contents {
           from { distributions.main.contents }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the distribution to contain the same files as the main one, though? I defined a new distribution like above, but no zip gets created.

Answer (score 5):

Using Gradle 4.8 I had to tweak the answer to use 'with' from CopySpec instead

```
distributions {
    zipWithJRE {
        baseName = 'zipWithJRE'
        contents {
            with distributions.main.contents
        }
    }
}
```